# Unable to Authenticate User in a custom controller using Spree / spree_auth_devise Gem - API only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

I'm working on a Spree Commerce application and attempting to create a custom API controller/page that requires authentication and I want to use the spree_devise_auth gem.
However, I'm encountering issues with authentication despite providing valid authentication tokens. Here's a simplified version of my setup:

I have a custom controller named Api::V2::CustomController located in app/controllers/api/v2/custom_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V2::CustomController < Spree::Api::V2::BaseController
  before_action :authenticate_spree_user!

  def index
    render json: { message: 'Custom Controller Working!' }
  end
end
```

I've set up a route for this controller in config/routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v2 do
      get '/custom', to: 'custom#index'
    end
  end
end
```

When I attempt to access the /api/v2/custom endpoint with a valid authentication token, I receive the following response:

```
{
  "error": "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
}
```

But actually the most intriguing aspect of this issue is that while I was typping this question I tryied to make the request again and got:

```
{
    "error": "The access token expired"
}
```

So now I'm very confused xD because its checking the token and all that but it just doesn't authenticate!

Here's what I've tried so far to troubleshoot the issue:

Double-checked the authentication token to ensure it's correct.
Verified that other "default" endpoints from spree, such as /api/v2/storefront/account, work correctly with the same authentication token.

I'm not sure what else to try to resolve this issue :/ Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I realise that the helper_method `spree_current_user` is available through out the application. When the `access_token` is correct, the helper returns the user object and if not returns `null`. So I can actually just make a simple `before_action` e.g. `:check_if_current_user` and authenticate it.